# PhoneGap and how it deploys

Tags: cordova

I have been asked to investigate PhoneGap and how it works. I can obviously see the main site and blogs about it, but none of them really seem to state "how" it works.

How does PhoneGap actually package up what you build in HTML/CSS/JavaScript into an app on your smartphone?

From what I can tell it bundles up all your calls into a custom web browser based on WebKit, which has custom hooks into the platform you are running on which you access via JavaScript API's. But this guess is pieced together from various old blogs and articles.

Is this correct? Are there any really good articles on this that I simply have missed?

Comment: Your synopsis pretty much sums it up well. The other main point is that it can do this for different platforms.

Comment: great, I guess I just wanted to validate my technical investigation into the product

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the introduction, this [PhoneGap for Engineers presentation](http://files.meetup.com/1715272/phonegap-for-engineers.pdf) provides some good PhoneGap nuts and bolts.

Comment: Actually, this presentation is showing that the PhoneGap Technique is the following: 1) Instantiate a chromeless browser instance 2) Implement PhoneGap.exec bridge code (JS -> native) 3) Implement native plugin code (native -> JS) 4) Implement JS API for calling this bridge (e.g. navigator.camera.getPicture). This technique is the same for each OS, only the implementation is different. The first three steps should always be done for each OS you want to support. The 4th step should only be done once.

Answer (score 4):

PhoneGap uses an extended version of the W3C Widgets specification for packaging, metadata and configuration (e.g. which device APIs are needed), and then runs this within a device-specific browser wrapper pretty much as you describe. It enables access to native device capabilities by mapping JavaScript Device APIs (similar to W3C Device APIs but in the Phonegap namespace) onto native APIs.

I wrote a short post on this here:

http://scottbw.wordpress.com/2011/10/07/phonegap-and-widgets/